# Updating and Deleting Associated Records in a One-To-Many Relationship using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, one-to-many

Using EF 4.1 Code First, I have a **Member** entity and it in turn has two "**one-to-many**" relationships for a **HomeAddress** and **WorkAddress**.  It also has a boolean property to state whether or not to use either of these addresses.

I have two issues that I can't figure out:

1. Whenever I update a member's address, a new record is added to the MemberAddresses table (with a new ID value) and the existing record is not deleted.  Though it looks fine from the front-end perspective as the HomeAddressId and WorkAddressId in the parent Members table is updated with the new record, the old records are kept in the table (orhpaned).  I don't want it to add a new address record when the address is updated.  I only want it to update the existing record.  If it has to add a new one, then I at least want it to clear out the old one.
2. There are times that I want to delete the address record from the table.  For example, if the member previously had an associated HomeAddress and later the DontUseHomeAddress is set to true, I want the address to be deleted from the table.  So far, I have tried setting it to null, but that just prevents any updates.  It doesn't delete it.

I'm sure there just some code piece I'm missing, so I'm including all the relevant code below that I think might affect this.

```
public abstract class Entity 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Member : Entity
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool DontUseHomeAddress { get; set; }
  public virtual MemberAddress HomeAddress { get; set; }
  public bool DontUseWorkAddress { get; set; }
  public virtual MemberAddress WorkAddress { get; set; }
  //... other properties here ...
}

public class MemberMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Member>
{
  public MemberMap()
  {
    ToTable("Members");
    Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
    //TODO: Somehow this is creating new records in the MemberAddress table instead of updating existing ones 
    HasOptional(m => m.HomeAddress).WithMany().Map(a => a.MapKey("HomeAddressId"));
    HasOptional(m => m.WorkAddress).WithMany().Map(a => a.MapKey("WorkAddressId"));
  }
}

public class MemberAddressMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MemberAddress>
{
  public MemberAddressMap()
  {
    ToTable("MemberAddresses");
    Property(x => x.StreetAddress).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
    Property(x => x.City).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
    Property(x => x.State).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(2);
    Property(x => x.ZipCode).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
  }
}
```

Here is the **InsertOrUpdate** method from my repository class that my controller calls:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
  private readonly EfDbContext _context;
  private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

  public Repository(EfDbContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
    _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
  }

  public bool InsertOrUpdate(TEntity entity)
  {
    if(entity.Id == 0)
    {
      _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
    else
    {
      _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
  }

  //... Other repository methods here ...
}
```

**EDIT: Adding in code for UnitOfWork and MemberServices**

public class MemberServices : IMemberServices
    {
      private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
      private readonly IRepository _memberRepository;

```
  public MemberServices(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
  {
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _memberRepository = unitOfWork.RepositoryFor<Member>();
  }

  public Member Find(int id)
  {
    return _memberRepository.FindById(id);
  }

  public bool InsertOrUpdate(Member member)
  {
//    if(member.HomeAddress != null)
//      _unitOfWork.SetContextState(member.HomeAddress, EntityState.Modified);
//
//    if(member.WorkAddress != null)
//      _unitOfWork.SetContextState(member.WorkAddress, EntityState.Modified);
//
//    if(member.DontUseHomeAddress)
//    {
//      //TODO: This is an attempted hack... fix it by moving somewhere (possibly to repository)
//      var context = new EfDbContext();
//      context.Set<MemberAddress>().Remove(member.HomeAddress);
//      context.SaveChanges();
//    }  

    _memberRepository.InsertOrUpdate(member);
    return true;
  }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
  private readonly EfDbContext _context;

  public UnitOfWork()
  {
    _context = new EfDbContext();
  }

  public IRepository<T> RepositoryFor<T>() where T : Entity
  {
    return new Repository<T>(_context);
  }

  public void Attach(Entity entity)
  {
    _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
  }

  public void SetContextState(Entity entity, EntityState state)
  {
    _context.Entry(entity).State = state;
  }

  public void Save()
  {
    _context.SaveChanges();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the state `_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;` doesn't affect the state of related entities. If you want to take care of changes of your related entities you must set their state to `Modified` as well:

```
if (member.HomeAddress != null)
    _context.Entry(member.HomeAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
if (member.WorkAddress != null)
    _context.Entry(member.WorkAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.Entry(member).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

This is not generic anymore.

To delete an entity you have to call the appropriate method to delete an entity; setting the navigation property to `null` is not enough:

```
_context.MemberAddresses.Remove(member.HomeAddress);
```

Comment: Slauma, thank you for your post.  I think I can understand it, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement it.  Please see my edited question above where I have added in my code for a generic UnitOfWork and the custom MemberServices that I call from my controller to InsertOrUpdate a member.  You can see the code that I have commented out that I am trying to get to work.  Unfortunately, when I try to use this code, I get errors.  Can you please look at it and see what I might be doing wrong?  I just added the SetContextState in hopes that would work, but I don't know if it's the proper way.

Comment: Here are the errors I get.  If I uncomment both of the address modified lines, I get "AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager" within the SetContextState methon in my UOW.  If I uncomment only one of the address modified lines, I get "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded." within the _context.SaveChanges call in the Repository.

Comment: @bmccleary: Both errors indicate that the primary key and perhaps also foreign property values are wrong. (Do you have FK properties for the two addresses in your `Member` class?) Keep in mind that by setting the state to `Modified` EF will create an UPDATE statement later, so the rows in the DB must exist and the objects must have key values matching to the key column values. Also: If you have a situation that a member has the same home and work address, make sure that `member.HomeAddress` and `member.WorkAddress` is really the same object and not two different objects with the same key.

Comment: Yes, the Member table is created with foreign keys named Member_HomeAddress and Member_WorkAddress and both are populated correctly (when my new code is commented out).  I just tried again, with uncommenting only the `if(member.HomeAddress != null) _unitOfWork.SetContextState(member.HomeAddress, EntityState.Modified);` and making certain that a record existed and the same `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)` error was presented.

Comment: By the way, I really appreciate your help.  If I can, I'll add a bounty to this question tomorrow so you can get more points for your time you put into it.

Comment: @bmccleary: Save the bounty better for your next question :) I've just tested it and for me it worked with my sample code above. `member.Id` must have a value with an existing row in the `Members` table and `member.HomeAddress.Id` must have a value with an existing row in the `Addresses` table. If that's the case I cannot reproduce the problem. Maybe you can edit an example to your question with the *exact* value of all key properties of `member.Id`, `member.HomeAddress.Id` and `member.Workaddress.Id`.